# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression when using replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using replaceWith to replace images with their source only. The code i am using is below

```
var html = 'Hello<div><br></div><img src="abc.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"><div><br></div><div>Video</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/40pH_we3niw" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"></iframe><div><br></div><div>Image</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><img src="def.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"><div><br></div><div>video 1</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LlW8tqMKEAM" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>';

var $html = $(html);

$('img', $html).replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).attr('src');
});

html = $html.html();

console.log(html);
```

But this is giving error as below

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

What is wrong with the code and how to fix this?

Comment: Remove the `hello` at the beginning of your HTML; it's trying to parse your string as a selector since it's not immediately HTML. Note that issues like this are fairly easy to figure out in the console, and that when reporting an error, it's important to be explicit with regards to when and where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention to which line the error is reported on. This has nothing to do with `replaceWith`.

It errors here:

> ```
> var $html = $(html);
> ```

The `$` function is *heavily* overloaded.

It does different things depending on what you pass it.

Even if you pass it a string, it does different things depending on features of the string.

The first character in your string is an `h`, which is not a `<` so it attempts to parse it as a *CSS selector* and not a *chunk of HTML*.

You need the string to have a root element for this to work.

```js
var html = 'Hello<div><br></div><img src="abc.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"><div><br></div><div>Video</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/40pH_we3niw" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"></iframe><div><br></div><div>Image</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><img src="def.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"><div><br></div><div>video 1</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LlW8tqMKEAM" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>';

var $html = $(`<div>${html}</div>`);

$('img', $html).replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).attr('src');
});

html = $html.html();

console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `replaceWith` will treat the replacement string as HTML. If those `src` values have any `&` or `<` in them, they could be mangled.